Getting NullPointerException while trying to Mock the CacheManager in spring boot junit
I am trying to write the junit test for CacheManger which is used in my code/project with mockito
but it is throwing NPE.
Here is the snippet
CacheContextConfig.java:
public class CacheContextConfig implements ApplicationContextAware{
  @Autowired
  CacheManger cacheManger;

  public Cache loadCache(String cacheName, Object key){
     return cacheManger.getCache(cacheName, key);
  }

  public void addCache(String cacheName, CacheData cacheData){
    //adding data into the cache , which is loaded on application start
  }
 
}

UserDispute.java

public class UserDispute{
   @Autowired
   CacheContextConfig cacheContextConfig;

  public String manageUserDisputeData(){
       //done here some business logic stuff

       VaueWrapper valueWrappter = cacheContextConfig.loadCache("userStore", "userKey");  //Here cacheContextConfig is throwing NullPointerExcepion
      
       // business logic
     return result;
   }
}

Here is the test class
UserDisputeTest
  @EnableCaching
  @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
  public class UserDisputeTest{
    
   @InjectMocks
   UserDispute userDispte;
  
   @Mock
   Cache cacheMock;
   
   @Mock
   CacheManager cacheManagerMock;
   
   @Mock
   CacheContextConfig cacheContextConfigMock;

   @BeforeEach
   public void setConfig(){
        openMocks(this);
    }

  public void testManageUserDisputeData(){
       
       doReturn(cache).when(cacheManger.getCache(anyString()));
       doReturn(valueWrapper).when(cacheContextConfigMock.loadCache(anyString())); 
       String actualResult = userDispte.manageUserDisputeData();
       //Do assertion stuff
  }
} 

the above CacheContextConfig class used to load/insert the cache data using CacheManger the same is used in UserDispute.java class with loadCache method
Thanks in Advance
When I tried to call loadCache method using mocked class cacheContextConfigMock , cacheContextConfigMock is throwing the NullPointerException.

[Edit] your question and post the entire message and stack trace for the NullPointerException.

How many parameters does CacheContextConfig.loadCache() take?  CacheContextConfig class suggests two, but the test suggests one.  Maybe both exist and you are mocking the wrong one?

What does @EnableCaching do and why do you need it in your test if your cache is mocked? @RunWith is JUnit 4, JUnit 5 uses @ExtendWith. You don't need openMocks(this) when your test class is annotated.

You stub a call with a single non-null String parameter:
doReturn(valueWrapper).when(cacheContextConfigMock.loadCache(anyString())); 

But your test calls a loadCache method with two string arguments:
VaueWrapper valueWrapper = cacheContextConfig.loadCache("userStore", "userKey");

Which means your stubbed call is never matched and valueWrapper will be null.
Either stub the right call or call the stubbed method.

Additionally, you seem to be adding and adding method calls and annotations without knowing what they are doing or what their effects are. You also seem to be mixing annotations from different versions of JUnit and that is not going to work.
@EnableCaching is a Spring annotation that only has an effect if you are loading a Spring application context, which is not the case for your test. So this annotation doesn't do anything, but distract from the real behavior. Remove it.
@RunWith is a JUnit 4 annotation, but @BeforeEach is a JUnit 5 annotation. Make sure your project contains only a single version of JUnit and remove all other versions (use JUnit 5 if you can). @RunWith has been superseded by @ExtendWith in newer versions of JUnit (5+).
Your test method is missing the @Test annotation. Without this annotation, it will not be picked up as a test and executed. Maybe it is simply missing from your sample code and exists in the real code, but maybe this is again caused by different versions of JUnit on your classpath.
MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) is the manual way of instantiating, assigning, and injecting Mockito mock objects. Since you already have @RunWith (JUnit 4)/@ExtendWith (JUnit 5), you don't need to manually assign the Mockito mocks. In fact, this might cause additional problems, because your Mockito mock objects are initialized (and injected) twice, which could mean that some calls are stubbed on the wrong instances!
I would also advise against field-based injection and migrate your code to constructor-based injection, as recommended by the Spring team itself:

The Spring team generally advocates constructor injection, as it lets you implement application components as immutable objects and ensures that required dependencies are not null. Furthermore, constructor-injected components are always returned to the client (calling) code in a fully initialized state. As a side note, a large number of constructor arguments is a bad code smell, implying that the class likely has too many responsibilities and should be refactored to better address proper separation of concerns.

